# Посчитать количество дней между датами, чтобы было не больше 750 дней

Tags: php, laravel

Человек вбивает дату начала и окончания, если выйдет так что больше 750 дней между датой начала и окончания, надо выкинуть юзеру ошибку, между датой начала и окончания должно быть не больше 750 дней, формат Y.m.d, не могу разобраться как это сделать, спасибо за помощь

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $earlier = new DateTime("2020-08-10");
    $later = new DateTime("2020-09-15");
    
    $pos_diff = $earlier->diff($later)->format("%r%a"); //3
    
    if($pos_diff>750){
    echo "Error"
    }
```

Попробуйте так должно получится